# Generalization of Vitali-Hahn-Saks theorem for algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

By Vitali-Hahn-Sack theorem, we know that, if $(\mathbb{P}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of probabilities defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ of subset of a set $\Omega$, such that for each $ F \in \mathcal{F}$ the sequence $(\mathbb{P}_n(F))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges, then the limit function is a measure on $\mathcal{F}$. I'm wondering if the same result holds true if $\mathcal{F}$ is just an algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and $(\mathbb{P}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of [pre-measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure) defined on $\mathcal F$ with total mass 1, i.e. if also the limit function is a pre-measure. Can anyone give me an answer or provide any reference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but 8.8 of Rao and Rao's _Theory of Charges_ might help you. There, they show a generalization of Vitali-Hahn-Saks for finitely additive measures defined on Boolean algebras with the Seever property. You might be able to use some of those ideas to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What follows is a counterexample.

Let $\mu_C$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. Define $$\mathcal{F}:=\{F\in2^\mathbb{N}\ |\ (\mu _C(F)<+\infty)\lor(\mu _C(\mathbb{N}\backslash F)<+\infty)\}.$$ Clearly $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Define $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall F\in\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}_n(F):=\chi_F(n)=\delta_n(F).$$ Then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it is clear that $\mathbb{P}_n$ is a pre-measure of mass $1$ defined on $\mathcal{F}$. Now, $$\forall F\in\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}_n(F)\rightarrow\mathbb{P}(F):=\begin{cases}
               0\ \  \textrm{if} \ \ \mu_C(F)<+\infty\\
               1\ \ \textrm{if} \ \ \mu_C(F)=+\infty
            \end{cases}, n\rightarrow+\infty.$$
However $\mathbb{P}$ isn't a pre-measure because, for example, $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(\{n\})=0\neq1=\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})$.